# How do I setUp a pickerView with 4 components, Arry? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I tried a lot but it just shows me "?" in the rows of the four components.
Is it possible to put a String at the first place in the Array Like as titles for the 4 components? I had the idea to change all the Integers in the arrays into Strings but it would takes me too long...

````
let componentOne = [1...1000]
    let componentTwo = [1...59]
    let componentThree = [1...59]
    let componentFour = [1...3]
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return 1000
        }
        if component == 1 {
            return 59
        }
        if component == 2 {
            return 59
        }
        if component == 3 {
            return 3
        }
        return component
    }
        
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            let row = componentOne[row]
            return 1000
            }
            if component == 1 {
                let row = componentTwo[row]
                return 59
                }
                if component == 2 {
                    let row = componentThree[row]
                    return 59
                    }
                    if component == 3 {
                        let row = componentFour[row]
                        return 10
                        }
        return row
                    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just change the delegate method. This is the [correct](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614384-pickerview) one:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
                titleForRow row: Int, 
                forComponent component: Int) -> String?
```

You have:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                titleForRow row: Int,
                forComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

You must return a `String?` no matter what -- if you change the function's return type to `Int`, it doesn't match the protocol requirement.

The good thing is that you can easily make a `String` from an `Int`. Just use String interpolation like this:

```
/// Inside pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)

let row = componentOne[row]
    return "\(1000)"
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you but the components are just showing the count of their arrays.... It does not continuous rotation

Comment: @EasyChris what do you mean by "It does not continuous rotation"? What do you want it to display?

Comment: I mean that every number of the array is in a own row. Like a normal pickerView, but mine shows me in the first component 1000x1000, second component 59x59..... It should start with one and then end with the last number of the array